# Submit a SGE job after another one has started (not completed)?

Tags: dependencies, sungridengine

I need to submit two jobs to a SGE scheduler (let's call them `JOB1` and `JOB2`), and it is crucial that `JOB2` does not start until `JOB1` does. I know there is the `-hold_jid` flag for submission with `qsub`, but that only holds a job until another is completed. 
When using PBS, I remember there was something like `qsub -W depend:after JOB1 JOB2` to have `JOB2` start only after `JOB1` started, but it looks like SGE does not come with this option.

This is for a Univa Sun Grid Engine scheduler system. Any idea on how I could manage this?

Comment: Interesting use case. Would you mind describing a little further why you need this? It sounds a bit like a race condition you should avoid by other means.

Comment: Maybe your system is different, but on the one I use you can run `qsub JOB2` inside the script for JOB1